# No route matches [GET] “/auth/twitter/”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, twitter, devise

I am working on Ruby on Rails application that can login with Twitter / Facebook account. They was working good until I accidentally use `bundle update`.

Suddenly I can't run my application since terminal / cmd keep sending me `Please add 'devise :omniauthable' to the 'User' model`.

So, I tried to added `:omniauthable`, and now the application can run, but when I tried to connect with Facebook or Twitter, I get `No route matches [GET] “/auth/twitter/”`

Anyone know why this happens? I tried to remove `:omniauthable` like said on several questions, but it isn't help.

***user.rb***

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :omniauthable
```

***omniauth.rb***

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, Settings.twitter.key, Settings.twitter.secret
  provider :facebook, Settings.facebook.id, Settings.facebook.secret, scope: "email, publish_stream"
end
```

***routes.rb***

```
  # OAuth
  get 'auth/:provider/disconnect', to: 'sessions#disconnect'
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#connect'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
  get 'facebook_disconnect', to: 'user_facebooks#facebook_disconnect', as: 'facebook_disconnect'
  get 'twitter_disconnect', to: 'user_twitters#twitter_disconnect', as: 'twitter_disconnect'
```

Comment: Can you post your `config/routes.rb` file? That's going to be the best place to start :)

Comment: are you using omniauth with devise ? have you placed omniauth.rb in correct folder ?

Comment: @RichPeck - Added routes.rb

Comment: @Dave - Yes, I am using omniauth with devise. I am sure its already in correct folder, since they working well before.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config| 
  config.omniauth :twitter, "TWITTER_KEY", "TWITTER_SECRET"
end
```

Comment: I tried to configured devise.rb as your code, but it still not working. The routes still not matches.